# error 500 when editing the .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm getting the error message

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500

I this is the code before I changed it

```
AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\security\xampp.users"
require valid-user
```

I changed it to this

```
# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----

ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

IndexIgnore *
```

I need a custom 404 page so people can't see my files.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should look like this `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` for 404 Page Not Found Error.

And to forbidding access

```
Options -Indexes
```

So you shall use this

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php
```

Make sure that you place the `filenotfound.php` page in the folder where you create the `.htaccess` file.

Here is the referal link for [Htaccess](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Comment: Is the .htaccess file and the filenotfound.php at the same folder ?

Comment: yes and now I'm getting this You don't have permission to access /xampp/Main-Page/style/ on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ok I fixed what I was doing wrong but now I can't find out to fix the 403 forbidden. here is my url and my .htaccess http://localhost/xampp/www/
# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----


ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/xampp/www/error404.html

# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on